# Is it possible to update a column(automatically) with "current_timestamp" in PostgreSQL using "Generated Columns"?

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns

Is it possible to update a column (automatically) with "current_timestamp" in PostgreSQL using "[Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html)", whenever the row gets update?

At present, I am using trigger to update the audit field `last_update_date`. But I am planning to switch to generated column

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN last_update_date timestamp without time zone 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (current_timestamp) STORED;
```

Getting error while altering column

```
ERROR: generation expression is not immutable
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that won't work, for the reason specified in the error.

Functions used in generated columns must always return the same value for the same arguments, that is, depend on nothing but the current database row. `current_timestamp` obviously is not of that kind.

If PostgreSQL did allow such functions to be used in generated columns, then the value of the column would change if the database is restored from a `pg_dump`, for example.

Use a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger for this purpose.